# Doping $\rm GaAs$ with $\rm Si$ atoms

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics

> A sample of gallium arsenide ($\rm GaAs$) is doped with 10^10 silicon atoms per cm-3. Ninety-five percent of the silicon atoms replace arsenic atoms and the remaining five percent replace gallium atoms. T=300K. The intrinsic carrier concentration, is equal to 9 x 10^6 cm-3. Find electron and hole concentration. Also find location of the fermi level.

My approach: Initially since no doping, we have ni = n = p = 9 x 10^6 cm-3. So when we replace with Si, I remove the extra one e from 95% of GaAs atoms so I can say p = p(initial) - 0.05* 10^6 and n = n(initial) - 0.95* 10^6. But after this I am not getting ni^2 = np, so I think I must be going wrong somewhere. :(

Comment: How exactly does adding a dopant decrease both $n$ and $p$?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Si atoms are acting as both donors and acceptors. Determine the donor concentration and the acceptor concentration based on if a group III or a group V is replaced. The difference between these is the majority carrier concentration and equals 9×10^9. Then find the minority carrier concentration from the law of mass action.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother